# Downloading the image from the server and convert

Tags: c#, image, xamarin

I want to download the image from the server and display it. I get header with type image/png as how now to convert to image?

I get header:

> Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400 Connection: Keep-Alive Date: Fri,
>   30 Nov 2018 12:32:08 GMT Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
>   OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1543581128745 OkHttp-Selected-Protocol:
>   http/1.1 OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1543581128514 Server: Apache/2.4.33
>   (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.0.30 X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.30
>   Content-Length: 26190 Content-Type: image/png Keep-Alive: timeout=5,
>   max=99 OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1543581128745 OkHttp-Selected-Protocol:
>   http/1.1 OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1543581128514 X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.30 }}

```
 public async Task<AvatarModel> GetAvatar(string dpi, Int64 uin)
    {
        var response = await BasicRequestAsync(string.Format(AVATAR_URL, dpi, uin), HttpMethod.Get, true, null, null, false);

        if(response == null) return null;

        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        .....
    }
```

Serwer:
HEADERS:

> IMToken: 123123123
>       uin: 123 
>    user-agent:...

Returns an unpackaged image with a heading
Content-type: image/png

```
 public class AvatarModel
{
    public AvatarModel() { }

    public AvatarModel(AvatarResponseModel model)
    {
        Id = model.Id;
        Base64 = model.Base64;
    }

    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    private string base64;
    public string Base64
    {
        get { return base64; }
        set
        {
            base64 = value;

            AvatarImage = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream(
                () => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)));
        }
    }

    public ImageSource AvatarImage { get; set; }
}
```

```
  public class AvatarResponseModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("base64")]
        public string Base64 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is AvatarModel?  How is the image represented there?

Comment: @Jason I added model above

Comment: Is the image downloaded from the url already Base64 encoded, or is it just a png?  You seem to be creating extra work for yourself by storing it in Base64 if that is not needed.  Generally the most efficient way to do this would be to write the image to a file and just store the file path in your model.

Comment: @Jason only png but base64 I have to another webapi where I use this. Whit base64 I do not have problem

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that, but I do not know if it's good?

```
 public async Task<Image> GetAvatar(string dpi, Int64 uin)
        {
            var response = await BasicRequestAsync(string.Format(AVATAR_URL, dpi, uin), HttpMethod.Get, true, null, null, false);

            if(response == null) return null;

            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            Image image = new Image();

            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(stream));

            return image;
        }
```